# Why adding action to button in UICollectionViewCell not working well?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I Have CollectionView which has multiple dynamic cells , foreach cell have button which has action to add number of items here's my simple code :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if ids.count == 0
    {
        return 3
    }else
    {
    return ids.count
    }

}




func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    if ids.count == 0
    {
        let cell = myCollection.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("loadingItems", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        return cell


    }else
    {
  let  cell =myCollection.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellProduct", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! productsCollectionViewCell

      cell.addItems.addTarget(self, action: #selector(homeViewController.addItemsNumberToCart(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) 
  }







    return cell

    }
}
```

and here's the method which adding items

```
func addItemsNumberToCart(sender:UIButton)
{

sender.setTitle("Added to cart", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
```

and here's my collectionViewCell class

```
import UIKit

class productsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var addItems: UIButton!

}
```

it's working and changing values but it's change values for multiple rows not only the selected row anybody now what's wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are adding the target but never removing it. So as cells get reused, the buttons accumulate multiple targets. There are a few ways to solve this; one is to implement `prepareForReuse` in your `productsCollectionViewCell` class (which BTW should have an uppercase P):

```
class ProductsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var addItems: UIButton!

    func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        addItems?.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it was mistake from me it's working :) Thank you